# How to directly connect 2 Ubuntu PCs via wi-fi?

Tags: networking

I want to create a direct link between 2 PCs via Wi-Fi without using a router to avoid a bottleneck.
What should i do? Both PCs uses Ubuntu 12.04 amd64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into setting up an adhoc network. That way the computers can talk directly.

To be honest though, I doubt you'll get much speed increase if any, because the limiting factor is more likely to be wifi transmission speed 802.11g.

Comment: thanks, i will try, the drivers for my ethernet makes Ubuntu freezing, i can't use the ethernet card.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry I thought you said **without** wifi. so Adhoc is what you're looking for.
But if you want the fastest, connect 2 PCs to a router with Ethernet.

Comment: i know, but i can't use the ethernet port.